Flutter try to implementing native view on iOS make app crash error Metal Impeller
I'm implementing the native platform view as documentation in Flutter website
but if running the app with Xcode all works fine the native view is shown, when run the app from Android Studio the app crashes at start with error:
[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/graphics/FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(42)] Using the Impeller rendering backend.
Already tried to disable it with the command
flutter run --no-enable-impeller

and also put in the info.plist
<key>FLTEnableImpeller</key>
<false />

but nothing change, I'm pretty sure that the problem is related with native view because if commenting the registrar in the AppDelegate the app not crash and pf course no view is shown.
here are some code of the implementation
iOS side:
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        
        weak var registrar = self.registrar(forPlugin: "QuickLook")
        
        let factory = FLNativeViewFactory(messenger: registrar!.messenger())
        self.registrar(forPlugin: "QuickLook")!.register(
            factory,
            withId: "QuickLook")
        
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}

class FLNativeViewFactory: NSObject, FlutterPlatformViewFactory {
    private var messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger
    
    init(messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger) {
        self.messenger = messenger
        super.init()
    }
    
    func create(
        withFrame frame: CGRect,
        viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
        arguments args: Any?
    ) -> FlutterPlatformView {
        return FLNativeView(
            frame: frame,
            viewIdentifier: viewId,
            arguments: args,
            binaryMessenger: messenger)
    }
    
    /// Implementing this method is only necessary when the `arguments` in `createWithFrame` is not `nil`.
    public func createArgsCodec() -> FlutterMessageCodec & NSObjectProtocol {
        return FlutterStandardMessageCodec.sharedInstance()
    }
}

class FLNativeView: NSObject, FlutterPlatformView {
    private var _view: UIView
    
    init(
        frame: CGRect,
        viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
        arguments args: Any?,
        binaryMessenger messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger?
    ) {
        _view = UIView()
        super.init()
        // iOS views can be created here
        
        createNativeView(view: _view, args: args)
    }
    
    func view() -> UIView {
        return _view
    }
    
    func createNativeView(view _view: UIView, args: Any?){
        let argumentsDictionary = args as? Dictionary<String, Any>
        let fileName = argumentsDictionary?["filePath"] as? String
        _view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        let nativeLabel = UILabel()
        if let fileName = argumentsDictionary?["filePath"] as? String {
            nativeLabel.text = "Native text from iOS \(fileName)"
        } else {
            nativeLabel.text = "Native text from iOS"
        }
        nativeLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        nativeLabel.textAlignment = .center
        nativeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 180, height: 48.0)
        _view.addSubview(nativeLabel)
    }
}

Flutter side:
class QuikLook extends StatelessWidget {
  final String filePath;

  const QuikLook({
    Key? key,
    required this.filePath,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This is used in the platform side to register the view.
    const String viewType = 'QuickLook';
    // Pass parameters to the platform side.
    final Map<String, dynamic> creationParams = {'filePath': filePath};

    return UiKitView(
      viewType: viewType,
      layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      creationParams: creationParams,
      creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
    );
  }
}


I have same problem, did you find any solution?
